# how to force android webview not to download and show images in order to save network cost

Tags: android

I need some technique by which I am able to not to download or show images in a web page while using android webView. My purpose is to save to network cost.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
vw.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
```

or

```
vw.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads (true);
```

[WebSettings docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html).

The first one is for images, the second one is for resources in general.

Comment: my purpose it is not to download image and not to show them, getSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false); and getSettings.setBlockNetworkImages(true); not working fine for me. means it does'nt load the page. some thing going to be wrong

Comment: Your purpose is to not download images, right? That's what the first one blocks.

Answer (score 1):

setBlockNetworkImage does the trick.

webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage (true);

**void setBlockNetworkImage (boolean flag)**

Sets whether the WebView should not load image resources from the network (resources accessed via http and https URI schemes). Note that this method has no effect unless getLoadsImagesAutomatically() returns true. Also note that disabling all network loads using setBlockNetworkLoads(boolean) will also prevent network images from loading, even if this flag is set to false. When the value of this setting is changed from true to false, network images resources referenced by content currently displayed by the WebView are fetched automatically. The default is false.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBlockNetworkImage(boolean)